# Need to know meaning of getopt.getopt in python

Tags: python

I am new to Python and got stuck in getopt.getopt

I know there is lot of documentation available but I am unable to understand this. I would be helpful if someone from python community assist me in understanding the same

Below is the code snippet I am trying to understand

```
import getopt

var1,var2 =  getopt.getopt(['-a', '-bval', '-c', 'val','efoo', 'cfoo'], 'ab:c:')

print var1
print var2
```

Output

```
[('-a', ''), ('-b', 'val'), ('-c', 'val')]
['efoo', 'cfoo']
```

I am unable to relate this how this happened

Comment: The documentation says: **The return value consists of two elements: the first is a list of (option, value) pairs; the second is the list of program arguments left after the option list was stripped (this is a trailing slice of args).** What part of that don't you understand?

Comment: @Barmar : I dont understand the first part. How it selects the list of option,value pairs. I know it is done based on `ab:c`. But what does it mean

Comment: `ab:c:` means it looks for options beginning with `-a`, `-b`, and `-c`.

Comment: Do you understand the general syntax of command line options to programs on Unix? If you do, this should all be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter `ab:c:` means that it should recognize options `-a`, `-b`, and `-c`. A `:` after a letter means that option requires a parameter after it.

The return value is two lists. The first list contains all the options, split into `(option, parameter)` tuples. The second list contains all the remaining arguments after the options.

In your example, options `-b` and `-c` require a parameter after them. So the first list contains `('-b', 'val')` because `-bval` is the `-b` option followed by the `val` parameter, and `('-c', 'val')` because the `-c` option is followed by the `val` parameter. `('-a', '')` represents the `-a` option, which doesn't have a parameter.

The second part of the result is `['efoo', 'cfoo']` because those are the arguments remaining after all the options.

Comment: Thanks but just a question. for cfoo why it has not make it ('-c', 'foo') ?

Comment: Options start with `-`, there's no `-` in `cfoo`.

Comment: Also, all options have to come before non-options. As soon as it gets to an argument that doesn't begin with `-`, it's done getting options.